# Typescript add custom suffix to compiled files

Tags: typescript

Is there an option for the ts compiler that adds a custom extension to the compiled files? eg instead of:

```
file.ts
  -> file.js
  -> file.js.map
```

to have:

```
file.ts
  -> file.comp.js
  -> file.comp.map.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as of know: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

If you're using a build system, like `webpack` you can do that.